# Movie where a guy is caught in an explosion and turned into a cyborg/robot

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie in the 80's.

All I remember is a guy was caught in an explosion of some sort. He was wearing goggles so his eyes were salvaged. He was made into a cyborg or robot, I believe.

It was not *RoboCop*.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds similar to "The Vindicator" (1986).

It is very similar to RoboCop, came out in the late '80s, and involves a scientist surviving an explosion in a lab and being turned into a cyborg. The trailer from YouTube is posted below. I'm sorry, the trailer seems to be in French, but you can see the scientist wearing his goggles 10 seconds into the trailer.

Answer (score 2):

This could very well be Sam Raimi's **[Darkman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkman)** (1990), featuring Liam Neeson. It has the explosion you mention. From Wikipedia:

> The blast throws a hideously burned Westlake through the roof and into the river. As a John Doe, he is brought to a hospital and subjected to a radical treatment which cuts the nerves of the spinothalamic tract; physical pain is no longer felt at the cost of tactile sensation. This loss of sensory input gives him enhanced strength due to adrenal overload and keeps his injuries from incapacitating him, but also mentally destabilizes him.

He isn't  turned into a cyborg or robot, however, but does get some superhuman abilities as mentioned in the quote. In addition, he uses artificial skin to impersonate members of a gang of crimninals and make them turn against each other.

[image: Darkman movie poster]

[image: Liam Neeson as "Darkman"]